# How to save sorted dict to list of tuples?

Tags: python

My problem has probably quite easy solution but I'm a Python beginner and can't do that.

```
b = input()
a = b.split()
from collections import Counter
myDict = Counter(a)
import operator
test_dict = myDict
wynik = sorted(test_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(wynik)
```

Why `wynik` isn't sorted?

Comment: `wynik` **is** sorted.

Comment: my input: abc abc qwerty abc bla bla bla abc my output: [('qwerty', 1), ('bla', 3), ('abc', 4)] I want to get [('abc', 4), ('bla', 3), ('qwerty', 1)]

Comment: You are using `itemgetter(1)`, Python's sequences are (like in every sensible language) zero-indexed. Use `itemgetter(0)`.

Comment: @filmor: No, most probably the OP wants to sort by the values, not by the keys, but in descending order instead.

Comment: Are you sure? It's not really unambiguous ;)

Comment: @filmor: The OP is using a `Counter`; yes, the test data is rather silly in that the keys end up in alphabetical order here, but why use `itemgetter` **at all** when `sorted(test_dict.items())` is enough to sort by keys in ascending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data **is** sorted. In ascending order by value. If you wanted to have the counts in descending order, use `reverse=True` to reverse the sorted order:

```
sorted(test_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Note that you don't need to sort yourself; use the [`Counter.most_common()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) instead:

```
wynik = test_dict.most_common()
```

This method returns the keys and counts in descending order already:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter('abc abc qwerty abc bla bla bla abc'.split())
>>> counts.most_common()
[('abc', 4), ('bla', 3), ('qwerty', 1)]
```

Comment: Why do you think he wants reversed?  He wants `[('abc', 4), ('bla', 3), ('qwerty', 1)]`, according to his comment.

Comment: @Alfe: Yes, by **count**. 4, 3, 1 is also a sort order. Sure the keys happen to be in alphabetical order too, but when using a counter, it's far more likely the counts are being sorted on.

Comment: @Alfe: besides, the logical way to sort by key instead is to not use a key function at all: `sorted(myDict.items())`.